# Can you optimize this descending sorting array with Ruby?

Tags: ruby, arrays, sorting

Do you know a better, faster, smarter, efficent or just more elegat way of doing the following ?

due this array

```
a = [171, 209, 3808, "723", "288", "6", "5", 27, "22", 207, 473, "256", 67, 1536]
```

get this

```
a.map{|i|i.to_i}.sort{|a,b|b<=>a}
 => [3808, 1536, 723, 473, 288, 256, 209, 207, 171, 67, 27, 22, 6, 5]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use in-place mutations to avoid creating new arrays:

```
a.map!(&:to_i).sort!.reverse!
```

Hard to know if it's faster or more efficient without a benchmark, though.

Comment: Cool! This really works, but let me see, just for a while, if someone else has other ideas ...

Comment: Be aware that that is an in-place mutation, so it modifies the *original* array. This is good for RAM, but may have side effects if that array is used anywhere outside of this scope.

Comment: If you want to preserve the original `a` array but still get some space and time advantages from in-place sort and reverse, just use `map` instead of `map!` in the above answer.

Answer (score 2):

Here's one using `symbol#to_proc`

```
a.map(&:to_i).sort.reverse
```

This is faster than using in-place modifier (`!`) methods but uses more memory. As a bonus, it keeps the original array `a` intact if you want to do anything else with it.

Comment: @edgerunner - What makes it faster than in-place? If anything, I'd expect the extra allocation to make the non-mutative method slightly slower (though not significantly enough to notice).

Comment: @ChrisHeald, I remember reading that ruby uses merge sort and in-place merge sort algorithms internally. See the [comparison](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sorting_algorithm#Comparison_of_algorithms)